# Best tool for unit testing in MySQL

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, stored-procedures, database-testing

I've been doing a lot of sproc programming in MySQL lately.
And I must say that I like it. A lot.

However debugging these babies sucks.
Anyone know of any tools that can put some happiness in My MySQL debugging?

Comment: There is no happiness to be found in MySQL stored procedures. You are doing it wrong. I have a longer answer^Wrant for you on that, but it will be kind of offtopic to this question, so I won't bother you with it here.

Comment: @Isotop: Thanx for making me smile, finally some glimpse of joy outside of MySQL.

Comment: @KingCrunch MySQL stored procedural SQL.

Comment: Didnt know, there is a real SQL-unittest tool. My question was about in which language you want to write your tests (java, ...). I think I need a closer look at mydebugger :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.mydebugger.com/

There is a limited free version, but the full version is not too expensive either.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hmm stepping through code sure sounds sweet.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using

https://github.com/hepabolu/mytap

For unit testing the db you should have something native that works in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

For Unit Testing, you can try this:
http://stk.wikidot.com/stk-unit

Answer (score 0):

If you pefer writing your test in C++ you can use googletest:

https://code.google.com/p/googletest/

You can find a good overview on the mySQL documentation webside:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/unit-tests-google-test.html